# ng-include not working in Plunkr

Tags: angularjs, plunker

I'm trying to experiment with `ng-include` in Plunkr but it was not working for me.

I then tried using some existing projects I found online and they too were not working, not in any of my browsers. 
For example, this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:4464334?p=preview

Does anyone else have this problem, or is it just me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Where is the file app.js in the plunker? It looks like you forgot about it**

Add app.js to plunker,

type in `angular.module('ui',[]);`

And it's working.

**A working:[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cx9YVEC4Bu82ur1MsvRM?p=preview)**